# Attempted to call function "getAge" from namespace "App\Bundle\Controller"

Tags: php, symfony

I am trying to instantiate a domain object in my controller but I am getting this error "`Attempted to call function "getAge" from namespace "App\Bundle\Controller"`". 
This is my structure folder:

[image]

this is my Cow.php:

```
<?php

namespace Domain;

class Cow {
    private $age;

    public function __constructor($ag) {
        $this.$age = $age;
    }

    public function getAge() {
        return $this.$age;
    }
}
```

My controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Bundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Domain;

class CowController extends Controller
{
    public function insertAction()
    {
        $cow = new Domain\Cow(10);
        $age = $cow.getAge();

        return $this->render('AppBundle:cow:insert.html.twig');
    }
}
```

I already tried all combinations of namespace:

```
use Domain;
$cow = new Domain\Cow(10)

use \Domain
$cow = new \Domain\Cow(10)

use \Domain
$cow = new Domain\Cow(10)
```

How can I make this work???

Comment: There are too many errors there. Please check [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php) for correct OOP syntax in PHP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following replaces:

```
<?php

namespace Domain;

class Cow {
    private $age;

    public function __construct($age) {
        $this->age = $age;
    }

    public function getAge() {
        return $this->age;
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Bundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Domain\Cow;

class CowController extends Controller
{
    public function insertAction()
    {
        $cow = new Cow(10);
        $age = $cow->getAge();

        return $this->render('AppBundle:cow:insert.html.twig');
    }
}
```

Basically, PHP's method/property accessor symbol is `->` instead of `.`. Also, for using classes within namespaces you'll need to indicate the whole route up to the class, with `Domain\Cow` instead of just `\Domain`

Comment: Thank you. I dont know why but getAge is always returning 0.

Comment: I set a echo "aaa" inside constructor but it is never shown in screen.

Comment: ohh, I was using __constructor and not __construct haha

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I'm not familiar with that dotted callings. 
But about your problem:

Try this:

```
use Domain\Cow;

$cow = new Cow(10);
```